# v-bind when variable is empty

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I use Vue and I have a variable. When the variable has a value then I show an image (pic1).

When the variable has no value (=empty) then I show another image (pic2).

My code...

```
<template v-for="(item, index) in items">
<img v-if="item.var" v-bind:src="'/images/pic1'">
<img v-else v-bind:src="'/images/pic2'">

<img v-if="item.var.length > 0" v-bind:src="'/images/pic1.jpg'">
<img v-if="item.var.length == 0" v-bind:src="'/images/pic2.jpg'">
</template>
```

I basically tried 2 independent options:

1. with v-else which did not work and it only showed me the posts with item.var (other posts with empty item.var discarded)
2. with .length - did not work at all

How to make it work?

Comment: You do need to key your image elements. Your `v-for` also does not have the `in variable` part that is required and this should cause a compile error. Other than that, I would expect the first option to work, but without knowing what is in `item.var` I can't really tell you what is wrong. Have you tried logging whatever variable you are looping through to see what is in it?

Comment: I'd think the issue is that you don't have a complete `v-for` directive statement. Should be `v-for="(item, index) in items` or whatever your items array is called. Otherwise, you should have a `key` attribute for each item in the the `v-for` group, but that wouldn't cause issues with the initial rendering. Here's an example codepen that might get you in the right direction: https://codepen.io/mcmillenb/pen/yLYNrqN

Comment: try `v-if="!item.var.length > 0"` for second option

Comment: Hey @Rju, show your items list what it contains ?

Answer (score 0):

What is item.var? Are you sure your file path is correct? And do you need both single and double quotation marks for the path? Remove one of the pairs. Images have a file type as well (eg. .jpg). If fixing those issues doesn't help, bind the image source with "require", for example:
`<img :src="require('./images/pic.png')" />`

Answer (score -1):

Are you sure that the data to v-for was passed correctly?

check your iterate item on item.var,

```
v-for should look like 
v-for="(item, index) in items"
```

I just checked with:

```
  data() {
return {
  item :  {
      var: [
        1,2,3
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

and i see mona ;)

```
 <img v-if="item.var" v-bind:src="'https://tineye.com/images/widgets/mona.jpg'">
```